# Anyone tried Cluster automation with WLST?

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, wlst

Most of the production env might need a automation script for Clusters. Reason is whenever there is a need of enhance the sites need to add new cluster to existing domain. When there is a decommissioned a physical site that needs removal of cluster from the domain. There is also possibility of "Growth" of Cluster (adding managed servers to a cluster). Finally there is also need of decommission of machines which requires removal of servers from the cluster. 
Menu
1. Add a Cluster
2. Del a Cluster
3. Add a server to Cluster
4. Del a server from Cluster

Please share your thoughts and suggestions...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually doing exactly that and it works fine.

You'll have to add the inital

```
edit()
startEdit()
```

and to save

```
save()
activate(block='true')
```

as well as exception handling but the functions are pretty simple:

Add a server to cluster:

```
managedServer = create(ServerName,'Server')
managedServer.setListenPort(ListenPort)
managedServer.setCluster(Clustername)
managedServer.setMachine(Machinename)
```

Delete server from cluster (and the server, optional):

```
serverMBean = getMBean("Servers/"+ServerName)
serverMBean.setCluster(None)
serverMBean.setMachine(None)
delete(ServerName,'Server')
```

Add a cluster (you can also use the same method as creating a server -> create(name, 'Cluster'):

```
cd('/')
cmo.createCluster('Cluster-0')
cd('/Clusters/Cluster-0')
cmo.setClusterMessagingMode('unicast')
...
```

Delete a cluster works the same way as deleting a server, you should power them down first though.

In general you can use the admin console to perform the desired actions and the record button at the top allows you to generate a wlst script which does exactly what you do in the admin console.