# Creating a managed server using Weblogic WLST

Tags: java, weblogic, middleware

I'm trying to configure weblogic cluster using WLST. When searching for script snippets for my Jython script, I came across this: [Anyone tried Cluster automation with WLST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166681/anyone-tried-cluster-automation-with-wlst)

I'm trying to find out more about the following method of WLST and whether it works for Weblogic 10.3.x

```
managedServer = create(ServerName,'Server')
managedServer.setListenPort(ListenPort)
managedServer.setCluster(Clustername)
managedServer.setMachine(Machinename)
```

I've never come across this method. What are the differences between this and using `cmo.createServer` to create a weblogic managed server? Are there any advantages to the former over the latter?

Answer (score 1):

They both have a purpose depending on your situation:

The *offline* wlst command is this. Best used for a new domain with no admin server running:

```
managedServer = create(ServerName,'Server')
```

The *online* wlst command is this. Best used for a domain that is already up and running:

```
connect('weblogic', 'weblogic', 't3://localhost:7100')
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/')
cmo.createServer('new_server')
```

You can learn more about the offline vs online options in the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/quick_ref.htm).